# Set of continous functions writable as cartesian product

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, product-space

let $(X,d_X)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^n,d_2)$ be metric spaces with $X$ compact.
Then the set of continuous functions is defined by
$$
C_n(X):=\{f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \;|\;f \text{ continuous }\}
$$

$\left(C_n(X),d_{\sup}\right)$ is a complete and separable metric space

First question 
(i): Is it necessary, that $X$ must be a metric space or is it also fine if $X$ is a compact topological space?

(ii) We can write $C_n(X)$ as the cartesian product $C_n(X)=C_1(X)\times C_{n-1}(X)$. Is this really obvious or do we have to proof this? I know, if we have $C_1$ and $C_{n-1}$ than it is not obvious that we can write $C_1(X)\times C_{n-1}(X)=C_n(X)$ because it depends on the properties of $C_1$ and $C_{n-1}$.

If it is clear, that we can write $C_n(X)$ as cartesian product, will $C_1$ and $C_{n-1}(X)$ be also complete and separable and why?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) For $C_n(X)$ to be separable metric, $X$ has to be compact metrisable (e.g. see the references in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/118461/2060). The result is true for both functions to the reals and finite-dimensional Euclidean space.

(ii) A function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous iff all
$\pi_i \circ f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous. So mapping $f \in C_n(X)$ to $(\pi_1\circ f,\ldots, \pi_n \circ f) \in C_1(X)^n$ is a linear isomomorphism between the spaces, and an isometry (I think) if we give $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the product $C_1(X)^n$ the max-metric (and base the $d_{\text{sup}}$ on the max-metric, which is topologically the same).

It's not a long fact to prove, but it does require a small argument such as  I gave above, IMHO.

A finite product of completely metrisable separable spaces is still of that type.

Comment: @GeoRie  And $C_n(X) = C_1(X)^n$ and $C_1(X)$ is completely metrisable complete, hence so is the power. The proofs for the product are standard: the standard product metric is complete when all factors are complete and separability is obvious: a product of dense sets is dense.

Comment: @GeoRie $C_n(X) \simeq C_1(X)^n$ is always true. From that: $C_n(X)$ is completely metrisable separable (Polish) iff $C_1(X)$ is iff $X$ is compact metrisable (as in the reference I linked to).

Comment: Thank you for answering. (i) is only for continuous functions of that kind $\{f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}|\; f \; continuous\}$. So you say, that a finite product of completely metrisable separable spaces is still of that type. So we can write $C_n(X)$ as cartesian product $C_n(X)=C_1(X)^n$ isn't it? Do you know a book where I can find the proof, that the finite product of completely metrisable separable spaces is still of that type?

Comment: ,do you know a book, where I can read that $C_n(X)$ is isomorph to $C_1(X)^n$? Thank you

Comment: @GeoRie I gave the argument in the posting...